# Finding the Z-angle position of a wall from a 2D image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have a 3D Rectangle wall in real life, which translates to a 2D image. considering that I have all his 4 points coordinates. how can I find his real Z angle position relative to the camera?

I tried to measure the ratio between to edges of the rectangle in different angles perspectives and with that, I can find and constant the if I multiply him with the ratio of the certain edges it will give me the current Z angle. It didn't work because when a rotated the wall the ratio between the edges didn't always change.
Is there anything else that I can do?

image 1:
[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/083FF.png)
expected output: 0 degrees

image 2: 
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQWsO.png)

expected output: around 20 degrees

image 3:
[image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQCr5.png)

expected output: around 45 degrees

Comment: First define Z-angle. is it pitch, roll or yaw.  is your height fixed e.g on a car? Can you show any input image and what you are looking for in the drawing so others can help you understand?

Comment: I added some examples

Answer (score 1):

**Basic mathematics**

Assuming you are having 2 2D images and you wish to find the rotation between them. E.g First image is front parallel 0 degree. Then the 2nd is the angle you wish to find.

Please go through some basics from here https://www.ifi.uzh.ch/dam/jcr:5759a719-55db-4930-8051-4cc534f812b1/VO_Part_I_Scaramuzza.pdf

[image]

It's in the capture of 2D to 2D motion from Image feature correspondence. There are too much mathematics involved. I`ll not go though all. Essentially, you are looking for an essential matrix which is rank 2 and contains all rotation and translation vector

[image]

[image]

The minimal case solution involves five 2-D-to-2-D correspondences as described in

E. Kruppa, “Zur ermittlung eines objektes aus zwei perspektiven mit
innerer orientierung,” Sitzungsberichte der Akademie der Wissenschaften,
Wien, Mathematisch-Naturwissenschaftlichen Klasse, Abteilung IIa,
vol. 122, pp. 1939–1948, 1913.

The more popular apprach is Longuet-Higgins’ eight-point algorithm aka. more than 8 corresponding matching points.

Just list down the matching point as shown below

[image]

Since you can calibrate the camera before handle, The F can be replaced by E directly.

Also you have to go through the epipolar geometry in Multiview geometry book as seen from the figure above

If your camera is RGBD camera, then you only need 3 points for matching, its called 3D to 3D motion estimation in the first link.

**Coding**

Assume you know all the background mathematics. Install opencv accordingly

Assume the image you used is in img1 and img2. img 1 is the front parallel. and image 2 is the rotation angle what you want to find.

```
  Mat img_1_c = imread(filename1);
  Mat img_2_c = imread(filename2); //each file should not have any color drawing inside
```

You can manually edit the matching points e.g 4 corners with a center dot

```
vector<Point2f> points1, points2;  //each topic have at least 5 point inside
```

The easiest way is to use feature detection routing in OpenCV (optional)

```
  cvtColor(img_1_c, img_1, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
  cvtColor(img_2_c, img_2, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
  featureDetection(img_1, points1);        //detect features in img_1
  vector<uchar> status;
  featureTracking(img_1,img_2,points1,points2, status); //track those features to img_2
```

if baseline movement is too large you can go with detector descriptor matcher way. (optional)

```
SurfFeatureDetector detector(400);
vector<KeyPoint> keypoints1, keypoints2;
detector.detect(img_1, keypoints1);
detector.detect(img_2, keypoints2);

// computing descriptors
SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor;
Mat descriptors1, descriptors2;
extractor.compute(img_1, keypoints1, descriptors1);
extractor.compute(img_2, keypoints2, descriptors2);

// matching descriptors
BFMatcher matcher(NORM_L2);
vector<DMatch> matches;
matcher.match(descriptors1, descriptors2, matches);

// drawing the results
namedWindow("matches", 1);
Mat img_matches;
drawMatches(img_1, keypoints1, img_2, keypoints2, matches, img_matches);
imshow("matches", img_matches);
```

**Enter your camera focal and principle point** from camera intrinsic calibration https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html

```
  double focal = XXXX;
  cv::Point2d pp(XXXXX, XXxxx); // this should be around the center of image if it is too far away, check you calibration process

Mat E, R, t, mask;
E = findEssentialMat(points2, points1, focal, pp, RANSAC, 0.999, 1.0, mask);   
recoverPose(E, points2, points1, R, t, focal, pp, mask);
```

the R and t contain the rotation and translation(not real world scale).

```
Mat Euler_vec;
Rodrigues(R,Euler_vec);
cout<<Euler_vec<<endl;
```

Then the Euler_vec should contain the angle you want. The value you are looking for should be at the either first or last column